# ms-appx not working for image in uwp assets folder

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've been stuck on this one problem for a bit and all I've found on the web seems to be a small variation of the same code involving a URI with the ms-appx scheme or baseURI. Nothing seems to work however.

Basically I have a UWP app with several pages. When I navigate to one of the pages I want to add an image from the assets folder of the app to a canvas on this page. When I do this in XAML the figure is added without difficulty.

```
<Grid Name="basicGrid" >
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/kamelenrace_background.png"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Canvas Name="GameCanvas">
        <Image Source="\Assets\kameel1.png"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

When I try to add the figure in C# code nothing works (one example I've tried)

```
 private Image player1 = new Image();
    private Image player2 = new Image();
    private bool singlePlayMode;

    public CamelRacePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        BitmapImage p1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets//kameel1.png"));
        player1.Source = p1;
        Canvas.SetLeft(player1, GameCanvas.Width / 2);
        Canvas.SetTop(player1, GameCanvas.Width / 2);
        GameCanvas.Children.Add(player1);

    }
```

While I might be able to make it work for now using the XAML, I would really like to understand why the C# code isn't working. I'm still learning...

any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you say "nothing works", do you mean the image is not there, or do you get an error?

Comment: the image is not there. no error
Also  found out now that the image shows up in the designer when I add it with Xaml, but is not visible when I run the app.

Comment: So I got the XAML code working after I rebuild the solution.
The C# code option is still not working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would really like to understand why the C# code isn't working

The issue is caused by the incorrect values of `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`  setting by code snippet. Since you didn't set the `Height` and `Width` values for `GameCanvas`, so that you will not get the `GameCanvas.Width` value. If you debug the code snippet you will find the value is `NaN`, so that with `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` values to `NaN`, you cannot see the `Image`.

You could just delete the two code lines the code snippet will work. Or if you want to get the actual `Width` of `GameCanvas` you should get [`ActualWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_ActualWidth) property. For example:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(player1, GameCanvas.ActualWidth / 2);
Canvas.SetTop(player1, GameCanvas.ActualHeight / 2);
GameCanvas.Children.Add(player1);
```

By the way, using XAML to set style and layout will be better.

Comment: Thanx! The (actual)width was indeed the problem.
I initially prefered code because I thought I could easily change the number of objects being added and alter certain properties to adjust for changes in screen size and some other features. 
I'm guessing you would recommend binding in the Xaml to alter properties instead?
What would be the exact advantage of that?

Comment: @ljanssen, you could search about MVVM, why this design mode take advantages.